# nested fragment + FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android-viewpager, back-stack, fragmentstatepageradapter

I'm trying to use a Fragment(parent fragment) with a View-Pager using the FragmentStatePagerAdapter (because dynamically adding fragments) having videos fetched from the you-tube in different pages of the view pager. when you-tube video is clicked in the view pager fragment(nested fragment) then the parent fragment is replaced by the another fragment which play the corresponding you-tube videos.

I am able to move back and forth between the 2 fragment(fragment containing view-pager and fragment containing you-tube player). but after some back and forth movement my app crashes due to **stackoverflow error**

After searching various blogs and post in stack overflow i find out my nested fragment is not popped from the back stack. I already tried the solution like -

```
public void onBackPressed() {
          if (!fragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate()) {
                finish();
        }
    }
}
```

where fragment is the fragment containing the view-pager but app still crashes.

Below is my crash report and related code

**Crash Report** -

07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192): org.pckg.name fatal error : null
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192): java.lang.StackOverflowError
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:747)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:898)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:977)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:329)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.Layout.draw(Layout.java:205)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.text.BoringLayout.draw(BoringLayout.java:400)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5030)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13712)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12650)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.widget.AbsListView.dispatchDraw(AbsListView.java:2327)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13715)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3653)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12650)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13715)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.draw(ViewPager.java:2153)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12650)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13715)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12650)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12694)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13428)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2928)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)
07-05 16:49:24.033: E/ACRA(32192):  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12648)

**Code** - 
Parent Fragment onCreate() method -

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "video detail frag onCreate");
    Log.d(TAG, "bundle of onCreate = " + savedInstanceState);

    if(savedInstanceState == null){
        gPageList = getFragments();
        ArrayList<String> pageTitle = generatePageTitle();
        gDetailPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), gPageList, pageTitle);
    }else{
        isCategoryTabAdded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isCategoryTabAdded");
        isSearchTabAdded = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isSearchTabAdded");

    }
}
```

**viewpager fragment onItemClick() code** -

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    if (gVideoList != null) {
        FragmentManager fragManager = getParentFragment().getChildFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragTrans = fragManager.beginTransaction();

        Fragment uTubeVideoFrag = FragmentYouTubeVideoPlayer.newInstance(
                position, gVideoList.get(position).gVideoId);
        fragTrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, uTubeVideoFrag);

        fragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
        fragTrans.commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: do you had any luck ?

Comment: Actually my problem is not because of the fragment actually but the library I implemented in my project.

Comment: I am also having same problem but using only support library. do you know the cause of stackoverflow and when to call child fragment manager I didn't find any helping tutorials. Please help me give me a tutorial how to add child fragments.